# Get function progress from nodejs and output it on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the code below that runs ffmpeg command my goal is to get the progress that shows correctly on server logs but the issue is I cannot figure out the logic to send progress and then end the connection after completing the additional code

```
// Progress Tracking
ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  if (timeMatch) {
    progress = Math.floor((currentTime / duration) * 100);
    console.log(`FFmpeg in progress : ${progress}%`);
    res.write(`data: ${progress}\n\n`);
  }
});


// Send the output file as a response once the process is complete
ffmpeg.on("close", () => {
  fs.readFile(outputPath, (err, data) => {
    async function uploadData() {
      const result = await bucket.upload(outputPath);
      if (result) {
        res.json({ mediaLink: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/${fileName}?alt=media&token=${idtoken}` });
      } else {
        res.status(500).send('Error: could not get media link');
      }
    }
    uploadData();
  });
});
```

On react client side I am trying with this but not sure if that's correct

```
.then(response => {
  const data = response.data;
  if (data.progress) {
    console.log('Progress:', data.progress);
    // Update UI or perform actions with the progress value
  }
  if (data.mediaLink) {
    console.log('Final data:', data.mediaLink);
    // Perform actions with the final data
  }
})
```

The error I get on nodejs server is

> ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Error on client side

> net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the way you are trying to do this is not possible with plain old HTTP.

Before you can send the body of an HTTP response, you must send the headers. After you send the headers, you can't go back or send new headers. It's a one-way thing. If you try to send headers multiple times, node.js will give throw the error `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT`. This is the error you're getting.

The first time `res.write()` is called, it will send some default headers if headers haven't already been sent. However, `res.json()` needs to send headers every time it is called because it needs to tell the client that it is sending JSON in the headers. So because you can only send headers once, you can either call `res.json()` once, or `res.write()` as much as you need. Not both.

If you want to stream realtime updates to the client about the progress of `ffmpeg`, then I suggest looking into something else like web sockets which allow you to do this.

Comment: it doesn't solve my problem, I don't want to use websockets , I asked a question to figure out how to establish the connection nobody could answer it

Comment: @Youssef The problem is that the method you're trying to do is not possible/supported by the protocol. You can't start by sending text with `res.write()` and then switch over to sending JSON with `res.json()` because it would require changing the headers. Also, regular HTTP isn't suited the protocol best suited for streaming data like this.

Comment: It is possible, I tried it to send all data as text and then using processStream and TextDecoder you can decrypt the response, and it does send it piece by piece here's an example https://gist.github.com/usfslk/20b9f14aa0d628d8b157ee0c4748eb44

Comment: Well yes, it is possible if you send the JSON as text, but your serverside code does not use `res.write()` to send the JSON. Instead of using `res.json()`, first convert the JSON to a string with `JSON.stringify()` then use `res.write()` to send the stringified JSON as text. Then from the client, you need to `JSON.parse()` the text. This way, `res.json()` is never called and you only send headers once.